# Construct a custom object whose properties will be enumerated in the order in which they were defined

Tags: powershell, serialization, reflection

I have an object that I created in PowerShell to fetch info from AWS.

```
$list = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
  'name'          = ($instance.Tags | Where-Object {$_.Key -eq 'Name'}).Value
  'baseAmi'       = ""
  'patchDate'     = ""
  'baseName'      = ""
  'owner'         = ($instance.Tags | Where-Object {$_.Key -eq 'Owner'}).Value
  'instanceID'    = $instance.InstanceID
  'imageID'       = $instance.ImageId
  'env'           = ($instance.Tags | Where-Object {$_.Key -eq 'EnvName'}).Value
  'instanceState' = $instance.State.Name
}
$baseAmi = Get-EC2Image -ImageId $list.imageID
$list.baseAmi = ($baseAmi.Tags | Where-Object{$_.Key -eq 'BaseAmi'}).Value
$baseAmi = Get-Ec2Image -ImageId $list.baseAmi
$list.patchDate = ($baseAmi.Tags | Where-Object{$_.Key -eq 'PatchDate'}).Value
$list.baseName = ($baseAmi.Tags | Where-Object{$_.Key -eq 'Name'}).Value
```

I would like to output the fields of the object in the following order:

```
baseName,baseAmi,patchDate,name,owner,instanceID,env,instanceState
```

This object is then exported as a CSV. I basically need the CSV headers to be organized in that order when viewing it in Excel.

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you using?

Comment: PSversion 5.1.14393.1480

Comment: This is always good information to include, as there were some significant changes between PowerShell 2 and PowerShell 3, so the "natural" solution - in this case, the Ordered Dictionary (my answer below) was not made available until PS3, so if you were using PS2, it wouldn't be a valid answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming **PSv3+**, always **use `[pscustomobject] @{ ... }` to create a custom object whose properties should be enumerated in the same order as they were defined.**

```bash
$customObj = [pscustomobject] @{
  name          = $null
  baseAmi       = $null
  patchDate     = $null
  baseName      = $null
  owner         = $null
  instanceID    = $null
  imageID       = $null
  env           = $null
  instanceState = $null
}
```

You can verify that the resulting `[pscustomobject]` instance enumerates its properties in definition order as follows:

```
PS> $customObj | Format-List
name          : 
baseAmi       : 
patchDate     : 
baseName      : 
owner         : 
instanceID    : 
imageID       : 
env           : 
instanceState :
```

Note that this only works with **hashtable *literals* preceded by `[pscustomobject]`**, which in PowerShell **v3+** is **syntactic sugar** to make PowerShell construct the **custom-object instance with the hashtable entries *in the order specified***, even though, in isolation, the entries of a hashtable literal (`@{ ... }`) are inherently *unordered* (their ordering is an implementation detail).

You can think of `[pscustomobject] @{ ... }` as an implicit shortcut for `[pscustomobject] [ordered] @{ ... }`, where `[ordered] @{ ... }` is PSv3+ syntax for a hashtable with *ordered* entries (keys), whose true type is `[System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary]`.

---

As for **what you tried**:

Unlike the syntactic sugar discussed above, **combining `New-Object` with a hashtable literal (`@{ ... }`) does *not* guarantee that the resulting object's properties are enumerated in the same order** as the (inherently unordered) input hashtable's entries.

Both `New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{ ... }` and `New-Object -TypeName PCustomSObject -Property @{ ... }` create a `[pscustomobject]` instance, whose properties, due the property definitions having been provided as a *hashtable literal* - in the absence of syntactic sugar - are defined in the unpredictable order in which the hashtable literal's entries are enumerated:

```bash
> New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
  'name'          = $null
  'baseAmi'       = $null
  'patchDate'     = $null
  'baseName'      = $null
  'owner'         = $null
  'instanceID'    = $null
  'imageID'       = $null
  'env'           = $null
  'instanceState' = $null
} | Format-List

imageID       : 
instanceID    : 
owner         : 
env           : 
patchDate     : 
name          : 
baseName      : 
baseAmi       : 
instanceState :
```

As you can see, the properties are enumerated in no particular order.

---

You *could* pass an *ordered* hashtable instead (PSv3+), but that amounts to the much more verbose - and less efficient - equivalent of the `[pscustomobject] @{ ... }` syntactic sugar solution above:

```bash
New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property ([ordered] @{
  'name'          = $null
  'baseAmi'       = $null
  'patchDate'     = $null
  'baseName'      = $null
  'owner'         = $null
  'instanceID'    = $null
  'imageID'       = $null
  'env'           = $null
  'instanceState' = $null
}) | Format-List
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is an [ordered dictionary](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/09/30/use-powershell-to-create-ordered-dictionary/). With an ordered dictionary, the order you define the tags in is preserved, so you would create them in the order that you want them to appear:

```
$list =[ordered] @{
    'baseName' = ""
    'baseAmi' = ""
    'patchDate' = ""
    'name' = ($instance.Tags | Where-Object {$_.Key -eq 'Name'}).Value
    'owner'      = ($instance.Tags | Where-Object {$_.Key -eq 'Owner'}).Value
    'instanceID' = $instance.InstanceID
    'env'    = ($instance.Tags | Where-Object {$_.Key -eq 'EnvName'}).Value
    'instanceState' = $instance.State.Name
    'imageID'      = $instance.ImageId
}

$baseAmi = Get-EC2Image -ImageId $list.imageID
$list.baseAmi = ($baseAmi.Tags | Where-Object{$_.Key -eq 'BaseAmi'}).Value
$baseAmi = Get-Ec2Image -ImageId $list.baseAmi
$list.patchDate = ($baseAmi.Tags | Where-Object{$_.Key -eq 'PatchDate'}).Value
$list.baseName = ($baseAmi.Tags | Where-Object{$_.Key -eq 'Name'}).Value
```

Comment: An ordered dictionary alone is not sufficent since the data is supposed to be exported to a CSV later on. Creating objects via `[PSCustomObject]@{...}` is the best approach, since it implicitly uses an ordered dictionary for the object creation.