# Build an array of data in a start-job in powershell and return it

Tags: powershell, start-job

```
$frontlineusers = Get-MsolGroupMember -GroupObjectID $frontline -All
Start-Job {
    $users = $args[0]
    $allusers2 = @()
    $svcaccount = "<accountname>"
    $admincred = GetAdminCredentials $svcaccount
    Connect-msolservice -Credential $admincred
    ForEach ($user in $users) {
        $msuser = Get-msoluser -ObjectID $user.ObjectID
        $pso = New-Object psobject
        $pso | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DisplayName -Value $msuser.DisplayName
        $pso | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Department -Value $msuser.Department
        $pso | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name City -Value $msuser.City
        $pso | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name FirstName -Value $msuser.FirstName
        $pso | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name LastName -Value $msuser.LastName
        $pso | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Office -Value $msuser.Office
        $pso | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name UserPrincipalName -Value $msuser.UserPrincipalName
        $pso | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name PrimarySMTPAddress -Value $user.EmailAddress
        $pso | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name PostalCode -Value $msuser.PostalCode
        $pso | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name State -Value $msuser.State
        $pso | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IsLicensed -Value $msuser.IsLicensed
        $pso | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name LicenseType -Value "frontline"
        $pso | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SamAccountName -Value $msuser.SignInName.Split("@")[0]
        $allusers2 += $pso      
    }
    Return $allusers2
} -ArgumentList $frontlineusers
```

The Jobs run but it doesn't actually connect to msol and pull user data and obviously I can't get it to return anything.  I have been trying setting the job to a variable using the $users variable as a defined param nothing seems to work.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As an aside: Unless you're still using PSv2, a much simpler and more efficient way to construct custom objects is to use the following syntactic sugar: `[pscustomobject] @{ foo = 1; bar = 'two' }` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45293404/45375)

Comment: $args[0] is only the first element of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note:

- The next section solves a *part* of your problem, but it doesn't address why `Connect-msolservice` doesn't connect.
- A *potential* reason is if `GetAdminCredentials` resulted in an *interactive* prompt, which you wouldn't get to see until you try to collect the job's output with [`Receive-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/receive-job)

  - If that is the problem, run `GetAdminCredentials` *before* starting the job and reference the resulting credentials object in the job script block as `$using:admincred`

---

`-ArgumentList $frontlineusers` passes the elements of array `$frontlineusers` *individually* as arguments to your job script block.

Therefore, `$args[0]` refers to only the *first* element.

There are two solutions:

- Keep your job script block as-is and pass the array as a *nested* one:

  ```bash
  # The unary form of `,` the array-constructor operator,
  # creates a single-element array with the operand as its
  # only element.
  -ArgumentList (, $frontlineusers)
  ```
- Keep your `-ArgumentList` argument as-is and replace `$users = $args[0]` with `$users = $args` in the job script block.

Comment: looks like that did the trick it's processing and getting the data now I just need to figure out how to get the data out of the job

Comment: @JoshT, for that you need [`Receive-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/receive-job) and [`Remove-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/remove-job) to clean up, though you can combine the two with `Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob`

Comment: Receive-job wasn't working with the Return<variable> if I actually just call the $allusers variable it shows in the output of the job and I'm able to return to the primary variable of the script.  Thank you very much for your help!  I'll post a full redacted version back once I get every piece setup.

Comment: My pleasure, @JoshT. Note that `return <variable>` is just syntactic sugar for `<variable>; return`, so the value of `<variable>` is output in _both_ cases - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55066394/45375).